# tf-idf on pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, textblob

I am trying to implement tf-idf without using sklearn and similar packages. Can someone help me convert values in a DataFrame to a list of blob objects?

I have a DataFrame with one column- "Text" and I want a bloblist as [TextBlob(Text1),TextBlob(Text2),...,TextBlob(Textn)]
[find image here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eWpC.png)

I tried:
bloblist=TextBlob(str(df["text"].values))
but this gives me just one list like    TextBlob(0  Text1,0  Text2,...0  Textn)

Is there a way to eliminate these preceding 0's...or is there a better way

Could someone please point out where I am wrong.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe help [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37593293/2901002)

Comment: I would like to avoid using sklearn package.

Comment: @ChandaKorat You seem to be adding the [tag:dataframe] tag to a lot of posts.  Please be aware that mass tagging should only be performed by users with 2000+ reputation points, and coordinated via a [meta] question with a consensus answer.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314488/how-to-deal-with-serial-tag-only-edits-from-sub-2k-users

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with calculating tf-idf values, but here is a way to get a list of `TextBlob` objects.

```
[TextBlob(t) for t in df.text.values]
```

Comment: This just returns me one TextBlob object with all the 'text'...[TextBlob("Text1","Text2",..."Textn")].

Comment: This will always return a list. If there is one item in it, then there is also only one row in the dataframe. Can you include a table showing the structure of your dataframe?