# Calculating IDF from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, tf-idf

I have a `DataFrame` with term frequencies (`tf`). The columns are words and the rows are documents. The rows sum up to 1.

```
|   A   |   B   |  C   |
------------------------
| 0.12  | 0.18  | 0.7  |
| 0.1   | 0.8   | 0.1  |
| 0.6   | 0.4   | 0.   |
```

What is the best / easiest way to weight these values with `idf` (inverse document frequencies)?

The thing is, `tfidf` of `sklearn` doesn't expect term frequencies, but word counts...

Comment: The easiest thing would be to pass df.values to an sklearn classifier...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest way to get tfidf with pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37593293/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-tfidf-with-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

If you define idf as:

> IDF(term, Documents)= |Documents|/(1 +|documents where tf(term)>0|)

you can easily calculate the IDF value of a term by using:

```
df[df['term'] > 0] / (1 + len(df['term'])
```