# How to convert document term matrix to tf-idf matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

[image]

Given this dataframe, how can I convert it to a tf-idf matrix?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Perhaps you'll find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37593293/how-to-get-tfidf-with-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @SerialLazer It's not

Comment: Then I kindly suggest you explain your use-case better

Comment: Try TfidfTransformer from sklearn